# is there a way to tell if a javascript function uses a rest parameter?

Tags: javascript, function, variadic-functions

I'm using a library that parses commands and applies functions to their arguments, and it checks if the number of arguments is correct before applying the function. It does this by checking the `length` parameter of the function. If I pass in a variadic function, however, this check fails when I pass any arguments, since `length` doesn't include the rest parameter.

Is there a way I can check if a function uses a rest parameter to explicitly handle variable numbers of parameters?

repro:

```js
function call_function(f, ...args) {
  if (f.length === args.length) {
    f(...args);
  } else {
    console.log("error! wrong number of arguments!");
  }
}

function normal_function(arg1) {
  console.log("here's the argument: ", arg1);
}

function variadic_function(...args) {
  console.log("here are the arguments: ", ...args);
}

call_function(normal_function, "hello"); // here's the argument: hello
call_function(variadic_function, "hello"); // error! wrong number of arguments!
call_function(variadic_function, "hello", "there"); // error! wrong number of arguments!

normal_function("hello"); // here's the argument: hello
variadic_function("hello"); // here are the arguments: hello
variadic_function("hello", "there"); // here are the arguments: hello there
```

Comment: "*it checks if the number of arguments is correct before applying the function.*" - it's not the job of the caller to check that. Move the check into the function definition itself.

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't really a satisfactory answer. I can't modify the entire design of the library and expect the library author to accept my change. I'd like to find a way to avoid this edge case specifically so I can suggest the change

Comment: In that case, I'd just use `Object.defineProperty(variadic_function, "length", {value: Infinity})` and ignore this weird design decision of the library.

Comment: I thought of that, but since it uses strict comparison having length be `Infinity` causes the comparison to fail.

Comment: Oh, I thought that was a `<`. Yeah, unless you want to use the function with a fixed number of arguments then, a change to that library is in order.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that good when it comes to regular expressions but I think something like this will work in most cases:

```js
const isVariadicFunction = f => /\.{3}[a-zA-Z0-9$_]+\s*\)/.test(f.toString());

function call_function(f, ...args) {
  if (f.length === args.length || isVariadicFunction(f)) {
    f(...args);
  } else {
    console.log("error! wrong number of arguments!");
  }
}

function normal_function(arg1) {
  console.log("here's the argument: ", arg1);
}

function variadic_function(...args) {
  console.log("here are the arguments: ", ...args);
}

call_function(normal_function, "hello");
call_function(variadic_function, "hello");
call_function(variadic_function, "hello", "there");
```

Comment: Most, yes. But regex is the wrong tool to do this properly - with the introduction of default parameter initialisers in ES6, you cannot use regular expressions to parse parameter lists.

Comment: That's true. The regex I suggested will definitely fail in that case (and possibly others). Just out of interest, can you explain why it is impossible?

Comment: Because JS expression syntax does not form a regular language. You'd need a parser that is able to handle recursion.